# django deposit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'

Tags: python, django

I am unable to access the `deposit()` method within the `Account` class from the views. Gives me the error: `deposit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'`
I am calling the method with:

```
Account.deposit(amount)
```

Views:

```py
    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'automatedbankteller/home.html')

    def about(request):
        return render(request, 'automatedbankteller/about.html')

    @login_required
    def transactions(request):
        context = {
            'transactions': Transaction.objects.filter(sender=request.user)
        }
        return render(request, 'automatedbankteller/transactions.html', context)

    @login_required
    def my_accounts(request):
        context = {
            'accounts': Account.objects.filter(account_owner=request.user)
        }
        return render(request, 'automatedbankteller/my_accounts.html', context)

    @login_required
    def deposit(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserDepositForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                amount = request.POST['amount']
                print(amount)
                Account.deposit(amount)
                #form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'The amount has been deposited into your account!')
                return redirect('ABT-my_accounts')
        else:
            form = UserDepositForm(instance=request.user)

        return render(request, 'automatedbankteller/deposit.html', {'form': form})
```

Models:

```py
    class Account(models.Model):
       ACCOUNT_TYPES = (
        ('SA', 'Savings'),
        ('CA', 'Checking'),
    )
        accountID = models.IntegerField()
        account_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
        account_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES)
        account_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.accountID)

    def get_balance(self):
        return self.account_amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.account_amount = self.account_amount + amount
        return

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.account_amount = self.account_amount - amount
        return
```

Urls:

```py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name='ABT-home'),
        path('about/', views.about, name='ABT-about'),
        path('my_accounts/', views.my_accounts, name='ABT-my_accounts'),
        path('account_history/', views.transactions, name='ABT-transactions'),
        path('deposit/', views.deposit, name='ABT-deposit'),
    ]
```

Forms:

```py
    class UserDepositForm(forms.ModelForm):
        amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

        class Meta:
            model = Account
            fields = ['account_type', 'amount']
```

Comment: `deposit` is instance method so u can't access it directly without instance. if u want to access make it as a `class` or `static` method.

Comment: Something definitely wrong with indentation in the presented code. You need (in your views): remove  line: `Account.deposit(amount)`; uncomment `form.save()`, more exacty replace it with `acc = form.save()`. further, add lines: `acc.deposit(amount)` and `acc.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

Account.deposit(amount) here Account is class . you need call the deposit method on instance of this class like.

```
account = Account.objects.get(id=1)
account.deposit(amount)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked once I changed the deposit method to         self.account_amount = self.account_amount + Decimal(amount)

Answer (score 0):

Your `deposit()` needs two arguments - the class instance and the amount. So you need to first create an `Account` instance and then use the method. Also, since you are not returning the updated amount, you can call `save()` method inside the method itself.

```
class Account(models.Model):
   ...
def deposit(self, amount):
    self.account_amount = self.account_amount + amount
    self.save()
    return
```

You need to call the `deposit` on an instance first.

```
# views.py
@login_required
    def deposit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserDepositForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            amount = request.POST['amount']
            print(amount)
            account = form.save(commit=False)  #no commit in DB
            account.deposit(amount)  # use class instance

            messages.success(request, f'The amount has been deposited into your account!')
            return redirect('ABT-my_accounts')
    else:
        form = UserDepositForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request, 'automatedbankteller/deposit.html', {'form': form})
```

You can also return the updated amount from the `deposit` method, but then you will need to call `save()` yourself.